# Nginx Https password protect

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, https, digital-ocean, nginx-config

Very simple. I need to password protect my `https://www.example.com` (in a digital ocean droplet).

I follow this tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-http-authentication-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-12-10

The problem I have, is that only `http://www.example.com` is protected, not `https://www.example.com`

How can I get HTTPS protected? (the HTTPS site works)

When going to:

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/myproject
```

This is my code inside:

```
server {

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;

 #   listen 443;
    server_name example.com www.example.com 143.xx.xxx.xxx;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/user/myprojectdir/myproject;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass https://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        auth_basic "Restricted Content";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am sure I am not the only one who experienced this

Comment: Do you have servers with "listen 443 ssl;" in Nginx configuration? You should add the same options (auth_basic, auth_basic_user_file) to server that listened https.

Comment: I get this error code when I edit the `listen 80` to `listen 443 ssl` , `Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
`

Comment: You may use `sudo nginx -t` or `sudo /etc/init.d/nginx configtest` for testing configuration before apply. I suppose that site with the same name and 443 SSL already exists